# How to restore bat file execution from explorer on XP

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-xp

some bat files need to be launched at the start of the session, but they don't.

Actually, when trying to launch one from the explorer, it opens the `Open with` window instead of just runnig.
However, the bat files still run correctly from the command prompt.

I bet it has been caused by a virus, but the antivirus did not detect anything unfortunately.

Any idea?

Comment: Is the file extension right? Does the icon look alright?

Comment: try renaming the file to `.cmd` and see if you can get it to work that way.

Comment: I think it belongs rather to superuser.com; voted to migrate the question there.

Comment: @SeanCheshire this works, but unfortunately, the .bat is used by all network users, and is loaded when opening a session, so I can't just rename it

Answer (score 1):

Use the Open With command, select cmd.exe, then before you hit OK, check the box that says "always use this program to open this type of file" or something similar.

If cmd.exe is not in the choices, browse to c:\windows\system32, and cmd.exe should be in there.

Comment: No I tried this already, and it just opens a command line window without running anything

Answer (score 0):

You can re associate the extension by downloading the reg file for batch from the link below which should solve your problem.

http://www.dougknox.com/xp/file_assoc.htm

Comment: I already tried this file, and it didn't work, though if I remember well, it restored the icon when I tried it

Comment: What does your regedit entry have for that key? Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: Yes I tried rebooting. Running "assoc .bat" in a command prompt outputs ".bat=batfile", and running "ftype batfile" outputs 'batfile="%1" %*'

Comment: I'm not sure then, maybe reinstall XP? I don't know what else controls the file assocs. Maybe someone over at [superuser](http://superuser.com) will know